# Java file.setReadable(True) not working, even on admin user?

Tags: java, windows, permissions

I don't understand why this isn't working
I know that the setReadable(True) method doesn't work if you don't have permission but I should because I am an admin user

I am on windows 10 btw

Can anyone help me with this?

Some more context on what I'm doing:
I'm working on a mod manager program that moves files into the steam directory, and can uninstall by deleting the folders. it keeps track of them by logging the paths into text files and if need be it can read from those files and delete the necessary folders. but every time i try to delete them, i can't because of an IO exception, and i know that it's because it's read only because i check for it

Comment: You run the program as admin ?

Comment: @xlxs yeah even when i run eclipse as admin it doesn't work

Comment: What file you are working with? You need System/TrustedInstaller privilege if it is some critical system/application file.

Comment: yeah, sorry I probably should've added some more context

Comment: I'm working on a mod manager program that moves files into the steam directory, and can uninstall by deleting the folders. it keeps track of them by logging the paths into text files and if need be it can read from those files and delete the necessary folders. but every time i try to delete them, i can't because of an IO exception, and i know that it's because it's read only because i check for it

Comment: Its better if you add the context in the question itself by editing it. But, not as a comment. It will helps other understand the problem and thus you too.

Comment: @glee8e do you know what I could do?

Comment: @ravishankar Yeah I gotchu, i edited the question

Comment: So, are you trying to delete a nonempty directory using plain file.delete()?

Comment: @glee8e no I tried using Files.delete() and I even tried using the Apache commons Fileutils.forcedelete to delete files (no directories) and it's not working, because i don't have read access and I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Try (file.setReadable(true, false)). Where you can indicate that you want the permissions set for everyone.

Comment: I'll show you exactly what I do: (where path_list is an array list of paths)     `for(String string: path_list)
  {
   System.out.println(string);
   File file = new File(string);
   file.setReadable(true, false);
   System.out.println(file.getName());
   System.out.println("readable?: "    + Files.isReadable(file.toPath()));
   FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
  }`  even when i use file.setreadable(true,false) it still returns false for isreadable